# OpenLayers3 control panel

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

Does anybody know what's the OpenLayers3 version of OpenLayers.Control.Panel? Couldn't find anything to group the contols (zoom in, zoom out, full screen, etc.) in a "navigation bar".

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no OpenLayers.Control.Panel. It's the application code to manage this part.

You have to make your own controls using HTML, JavaScript and CSS.
See this official example to understand how to do it http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/custom-controls.html